# Replace whatever comes in specific field with awk

Tags: replace, awk

Suppose I have data like

```
name,age

sam,20

pam,30
```

I want to replace whatever comes in field 2 (i.e 20 and 30) with a given value stored in a variable var=10. I specifically dont want to do the same for first line.

desired o/p

```
name,age

sam,10

pam,10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," -v n="10" 'NR>1&&NF==2{$2=n}7' file
```

test:

```
kent$ (US-6966|✔) echo "name,age

sam,20

pam,30"|awk -F, -v OFS="," -v n="10" 'NR>1&&NF==2{$2=n}7'
name,age

sam,10

pam,10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk command to replace the value in column two with the value stored in a variable(ie, 10),

```
$ awk -F, -v var=10 'NR==1{print; next} /^ *$/{next}{gsub(/.*/,var,$2)}1' OFS="," file
name,age
sam,10
pam,10
```

**OR**

if you want to print the blank lines also then try this command,

```
$ awk -F, -v var=10 'NR==1{print; next} /^ *$/{print; next}{gsub(/.*/,var,$2)}1' OFS="," file
name,age

sam,10

pam,10
```